# How can I perform route model binding on a computed column or a scope in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

Assume the following data in my table 'words':

```
+----+----------------+
+ id + Title          +
+ 1  + Lorem ipsum    +
+ 2  + Dolor sit amet +
+----+----------------+
```

The `Word` model contains the following scope:

```
// app/Models/Words.php
public function scopeByWords($query, $words)
{
    return $query->where('id', wordsToNumber($words));
}
```

The idea is that `example.com/one` should return row id 1, `example.com/two` should return row id 2 and so on.

Assuming the functions `wordsToNumber` and `numberToWords` are written, how can I perform route model binding in this case? The following code does not work. It throws up a 404.

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/{words}', 'WordsController@show');

// app/Providers/RoutingServiceProvider.php
Route::bind('words', function ($words) {
    return Word::byWords($words)->get() ?? abort(404);
});
```

If I do this manually, I am able to pull the row out:

```
// app/Http/Controllers/WordsController.php
public function show($words) {
    return Word::byWords($words)->get();
}
```

I want to know why the following doesn't work:

```
// app/Http/Controllers/WordsController.php
public function show(Word $words) {
    return $words;
}
```

This is obviously an example of the problem I'm looking to solve. The actual transformation of the query string to the row is different.

Comment: In your `Route::bind` example you have `Bunch::byWord(...` but in your controller method example you have ` Word::byWords(...`. Is `Bunch` and `Word` the same class in this instance and if so, why are you calling different methods on them?

Comment: I pasted the wrong code in!

Comment: Your Route::bind is still showing as `byWord` instead of `byWords`

Comment: Only typos, my friend, only typos! I have checked the real code and it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. I only had to replace the `get()` method, which returns a collection, with `first()`, which returns a single object.

```
// app/Providers/RoutingServiceProvider.php
Route::bind('words', function ($words) {
    return Word::byWords($words)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

This was a really silly oversight on my part.